# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'host' of undefined in Durandal when showing/closing modal dialog

Tags: durandal

Using Durandal 2.0.1 (can't update to 2.1.0 yet due to restrictions on project development) and I have an intermittent issue with the error shown in this question title.

All I'm doing is defining a custom dialog box then showing it:

```
    var pleaseWaitModal = new modalBusy();
    dialog.show(pleaseWaitModal);
```

And when my ajax call is finished I do:

```
    dialog.close(pleaseWaitModal);
```

...and then display another modal with the results of my ajax call.

This all works perfectly IF the ajax call takes half a second to a second. If it's a quicker call then I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'host' of undefined` in my console window.  The box still closes, it's just that I get a panicky project manager asking what the red error is for...

Is this purely because I'm trying to run "dialog.close()" before "dialog.show()" has properly completed in some circumstances?

The sequence of events is basically:

```
*user instigates action requiring a detailed modal dialog to appear with data in it
*as it takes several seconds to populate on some occasions, an interim modal dialog is shown with "please wait" in it
*once the ajax request is complete, the "pleasewait" modal is closed and the "detail" modal is shown

*so a bit like:
    var pleaseWaitModal = new modalBusy();
    dialog.show(pleaseWaitModal);

    //set up deferred calls for ajax data and call ...
    var deferredAjax = callDataFunction(myparams...);
    return deferredAjax.then(function(result) {
         dialog.close(pleaseWaitModal);
         var detailModal = new detailModal();
         detailModal.show(result);
    });
```

So I don't think I can achieve this using the promise on the `dialog.show(pleaseWaitModal)` call, can I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the promise that is returned from the dialog.close function to open your new modal? You might try this:

From your initial dialog:

```
dialog.show(new modal()).then(function(responseData) { 
    dialog.show(new pleaseWaitModal(responseData)); 
});
```

I think the problem you're running into is async timing related, which is why using the deferred works so well.

**EDIT:** Related to my comment below, you might look at using only one modal, and putting a loading indicator inside of it, like so:

*view.html*

```
<div data-bind="visible: isLoading">
    <h1>Please wait...</h1>
    <i class="icon-spin icon-spinner icon-4x"></i>
</div>
```

*modalViewModel.js*

```
var vm = {
    isLoading: ko.observable(true)
};

vm.activate = function() {
    makeAjaxCall().then(function(data) {
        vm.isLoading(false);
        **Do whatever you need for your ajax return**
        return true;
    });
});
```

I think that should work for what you need as an alternative.

Comment: I can't do it this way (I don't think) as the "pleasewait" modal is a simple modal showing "please wait" and a spinner animation. There is no "close" button on it. The showing/closing of this dialog is entirely controlled by the main program logic. Will edit original question to show more info.

Comment: OK, I just read through what you wrote initially with a little greater attention to detail.  Sorry about that. Instead of popping a separate modal, what if you were to show a loading indicator in the modal you're actually doing the work in? So, you'd have a div with the text and spinner icon data-bound to an isLoading observable that  would be true by default and set to false when the deferred resolved?  I know that doesn't EXACTLY answer your question, but it might make life easier for you.

Comment: Ah, but the problem is the modal sizes to the content first passed (small as it's "please wait" and then it has to display a large amount and this screws up the positioning of the modal :-( Fixed in 2.1, I can't upgrade to that yet.

Comment: I think the way I got around that was to use a min-width property on the Modal definition, but I can see where that might be an issue.  Ok, how about using an alternative like jQuery Block UI instead, so instead of showing the "Please Wait" modal, block the UI while you're doing the AJAX call?  Another alternative might be to use a setTimeout on the dialog.show, since it is almost certainly a timing issue.

Comment: One more alternative might be to override the default behavior of the dialog.close to return a promise, and that way, you can be sure you're waiting until the close function is done before calling the show function of the next modal.

Comment: Finally back on this after days trying to sort out a problem elsewhere! So if I was to try and override the close behaviour of dialog, would I have to do that directly in the code for plugins/dialog.js on the `close: function(obj){...` method?

Comment: Have to say I'm quite surprised that Durandal's `dialog.close` doesn't return a promise already, but I suppose they never envisaged it being used as an interstitial notification system like I'm trying to!

Comment: Yeah, I actually went and looked at the code myself because I expected it to return a promise.  None the less, it should be relatively easy to override that code on the close: function(obj) method.

Comment: I was concerned about doing this as a simple nuget update would wipe out my code change. I decided to simply add a 300ms timeout delay to the call and give the window time to close!  That has worked fine.  I'll accept your answer anyway as I appreciate the help you've offered!

Comment: Yeah, the timeout is certainly a way to do it, and sometimes, even though it's not the best way according to the textbook, it's the best way in practice.  Glad it's working for you!  I might just submit a pull request with the close function returning a promise.  Who knows, maybe it'll be useful to others.  Thanks for accepting my answer!